# Как настроить форматирование кода vscode на linux?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Как на линуксе настроить форматирование кода? На Ubuntu не работает на комбинацию CTRL + S так настроено у меня в настроках.

Answer (score 2):

Отформатировать код в текущем файле можно сочетанием клавиш на Linux:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Переназначить сочетание можно в разделе "Keyboard Shortcuts" (можно открыть, нажав на шестерню в левом нижнем углу), команда называется "Format Document".

Если необходимо автоматически форматировать код при сохранении файлов, можно активировать опцию "Format On Save" в настройках VS Code.